# Print to terminal after final compiler message?

Tags: terminal-output

I use only lualatex, but I believe this is a general *.tex question:

Compiling from command line (Linux, probably any system), the Terminal
response concludes with something like this:

```
507 words of node memory still in use:
...
...
Output written on xxx.pdf (7 pages, 63101 bytes).
Transcript written on xxx.log.
```

I would like to place a message following that, just above where the
Terminal returns to command prompt. Is this possible?

It does not help to use package `atveryend`.
If I write `\AtVeryVeryEnd{\typeout{DONE!}}` it appears above the concluding
message shown above.

Why I want to do this: I have a custom document class that analyzes the
user settings and font metrics, and provides important information.
This, I know how to do. But the information is always displayed above the
concluding TeX message, where a user might ignore it. The users are not
programmers, so they have no use for the TeX info regarding memory, etc.

I cannot use shell escape.

Comment: well in luatex you could probably use the stop_run callback, see the docu.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Eeek. I will have a look there, but hoped it would be something simple (for simple-minded folks, such as myself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that in classic tex, but luatex gives you Lua access.

Terminal output ending in "hello world"

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./ee276.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-10-23>
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def)
(./ee276.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./ee276.aux))</usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmro
man10-regular.otf>

hello world
```

From

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{
luatexbase.add_to_callback('stop_run',
function ()
texio.write("\string\n\string\n hello world\string\n")
end,
"final message"
)
}
\begin{document}

aaa


\end{document}
```

As seen above, `stop_run` callback *replaces* the usual printing of statistics. If you replace `stop_run` by `wrapup_run` then it comes *after* the usual statistics are printed

The documentation of this callback is, in full

> This callback is called after the pdf and log files are closed. Use it at your own risk.

But I think it's safe enough here

```
$ lualatex ee276
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./ee276.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-10-23>
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def)
(./ee276.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./ee276.aux))
 406 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec
, 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:22,3:4,4:1,5:22,6:2,7:34,9:18
</usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.
otf>
Output written on ee276.pdf (1 page, 2613 bytes).
Transcript written on ee276.log.


hello world
```

Comment: Yay! That is what I need! I added `\string\n` after the text, so that the terminal prompt is returned to the left.

Comment: For the benefit of others who find this thread: If the message is more than one word, do something like this: `texio.write("\string\n\string\nHello,\space World.\string\n")`

Comment: On my system, just typing a space does not necessarily work. The words join (might make a difference if there is punctuation or not). I needed `\space` before the typed space.

Comment: @rallg oh sure that's just normal "space after a command name" and you have `\nHello`  so the space is dropped after it.  but not after a comma or a word like `Hello` so you could use a space after the `\n`: so  `\string\n Hello World`

Comment: @rallg second example using `wrapup_run` added